# NUnit Visual Studio run TearDown on test cancel

Tags: c#, automated-tests, nunit

Is there a way to make NUnit tests run their [TearDown] method when a test is interrupted by clicking on "Cancel" in the Test Explorer?

At the moment all that happens is the test stops executing and the browser stays open.

Thanks

Comment: Which version of NUnit?

Comment: @WaiHaLee Version 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, if you cancel the test running, VS simply stops the execution, nothing more of your code is executed, even "IDisposable" implementation or "try/finally" statements.